# Need grep help on substring pattern from one file and match against another to see if pattern exists

Tags: grep

I have an input flat file like this with many rows:

```
Apr  3 13:30:02 aag8-ca-acs01-en2 CisACS_01_PassedAuth p1n5ut5s 1 0   Message-Type=Authen OK,User-Name=joe7@it.test.com,NAS-  IP-Address=4.196.63.55,Caller-ID=az-4d-31-89-92-90,EAP Type=17,EAP Type Name=LEAP,Response Time=0,
Apr  3 13:30:02 aag8-ca-acs01-en2 CisACS_01_PassedAuth p1n6ut5s 1 0 Message-Type=Authen OK,User-Name=bobe@jg.test.com,NAS-IP-Address=4.197.43.55,Caller-ID=az-4d-4q-x8-92-80,EAP Type=17,EAP Type Name=LEAP,Response Time=0,
Apr  3 13:30:02 abg8-ca-acs01-en2 CisACS_01_PassedAuth p1n4ut5s 1 0 Message-Type=Authen OK,User-Name=jerry777@it.test.com,NAS-IP-Address=7.196.63.55,Caller-ID=az-4d-n6-4e-y2-90,EAP Type=17,EAP Type Name=LEAP,Response Time=0,
Apr  3 13:30:02 aca8-ca-acs01-en2 CisACS_01_PassedAuth p1n4ut5s 1 0 Message-Type=Authen OK,User-Name=frctom@pe.test.com,NAS-IP-Address=4.196.263.55,Caller-ID=az-4d-x1-d3-c2-90,EAP Type=17,EAP Type Name=LEAP,Response Time=0,
Apr  3 13:30:02 aag8-ca-acs01-en2 CisACS_01_PassedAuth p1n4ut5s 1 0 Message-Type=Authen OK,User-Name=frc77@xed.test.com,NAS-IP-Address=4.136.163.55,Caller-ID=az-4d-4w-b5-s2-90,EAP Type=17,EAP Type Name=LEAP,Response Time=0,
Apr  3 13:30:02 aag8-ca-acs01-en2 CisACS_01_PassedAuth p1n4ut5s 1 0 Message-Type=Authen OK,User-Name=petejg@it.test.com,NAS-IP-Address=4.136.62.55,Caller-ID=az-4e-31-x3-92-c0,EAP Type=17,EAP Type Name=LEAP,Response Time=0
```

I'm trying to grep the email addresses from input file to see if they already exist in the master file.

Master flat file looks like this:

```
a44e31999290;frc777o.@it.test.com;20150403
az4d4qx89280;bobe@jg.test.com;20150403
0dbgd0fed04t;rrfuf@us.test.com;20150403
28cbe9191d53;rttuu4en@us.test.com;20150403
az4d4wb5s290;frc77@xed.test.com;20150403
d89695174805;ccis6n@cn.test.com;20150403
s00dbg0fe04t;rrfuuuf@be.test.com;20150403
```

If the email doesn't exist in master I want a simple count.  So using the examples I hope to see `count=5 (bobe@jg.test.com & frc77@xed.test.com exist in master but the others don't).

I have tried various combinations of grep, the one below is what I was testing last but it still does not work.. I'm using this within a perl script to first capture emails and then count them but all I really need is the count of emails from input file that don't exist in master.

`grep -o -P '(?<=User-Name=\).*(?=,NAS-IP-)' $infile $mstr > $new_emails`;

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly a one-liner, but this works for me:

```
for email in $(sed "s/.*User-Name=\(.[^,]*\),.*/\1/g" input.txt); do
grep -oc $email master.txt
done | sort | uniq -c | awk '{if ($2==0) print $1}'
```

**Explanation:**

The sed command gets me a clean list of email addresses from the input file:

```
$ sed "s/.*User-Name=\(.[^,]*\),.*/\1/g" input.txt
joe7@it.test.com
bobe@jg.test.com
jerry777@it.test.com
frctom@pe.test.com
frc77@xed.test.com
petejg@it.test.com
```

The grep command looks for each of these addresses in the master file and (because of the -c flag) returns 0 for no match and 1 for match:

```
$ for email in $(sed "s/.*User-Name=\(.[^,]*\),.*/\1/g" input.txt); do 
$ grep -oc $email master.txt 
$ done
0
1
0
0
1
0
```

The sort and uniq commands get the frequency of matches and non-matches:

```
$ |sort | uniq -c 
4 0
2 1
```

And finally the awk command prints out the number of non-matches (it will print the first column only if the second column is 0):

```
$ awk '{if ($2==0) print $1}' 
4
```